# How do I delete multiple row ranges simultaneously for all excel sheets?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file with around 50 sheets for which I need to remove these row ranges:
57-62, 113-118, 169-174,etc. I need to do that because there are discontinuous rows. I mean I have data from the row (1-56), then I have words that are contaminating my data(113-118) and then clear data , and so on. So I want to delete  multiple row ranges simultaneously for all excel sheets.

I was trying with this code:

```
Sub WorksheetLoop1()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Range("57:62").EntireRow.Delete
    Next ws

End Sub
Sub WorksheetLoop2()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Range("113:118").EntireRow.Delete
    Next ws

End Sub
```

But there is a mistake when I run the first code( Sub WorksheeyLoop1() ), and then run the next one. The
range obviously change from 113-118 to 107-112. I don't want that. I want to run all the code simultaneously(eliminate simultaneously multiple row ranges ) for each excel sheet so I don't have to change the row ranges for each code.
. Could you please suggest VBA code for doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When deleting multiple rows sections start with the highest row numbers first then work down so your rows won't be affect by the shift. Something like this should solve your issue.

```
 Sub WorksheetLoop()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Range("169:174").EntireRow.Delete
        ws.Range("113:118").EntireRow.Delete
        ws.Range("57:62").EntireRow.Delete
    Next ws
    End Sub
```

Comment: Note that this deletes them sequencially not really **at once** as requested. Use just one line `ws.Range("57:62,113:118,169:174").EntireRow.Delete` to **really** delete them at once and not sequencially. Note that this syntax has a limit in length of 255 characters. Another alternative to **really** delete them at once is to use the [Application.Union method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.union) first and then delete the unified range **at once**.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Thank you, it was that I looking for.